# QWebview, webview->load(QUrl) makes the application crash

Tags: c++, qt, fedora, qwebview, qtwebengine

I am working in C++/Qt Embedded project where fedora operating  is used. I use QWebview to display html pages. but when i load the page using 
webview->load(Qurl), It crashes. I have also tried webview->setHtml().

The same works fine in windows.

My Qt version it 5.3.0 . I just searched and found that Qwebengine will resolve this issue, But it is not available in 5.3.0. Is there any way to integrate Qwebengine in 5.3.0 ?

Please help me where is the problem and how to resolve this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you provide the link which say that Qwebengine will resolve this issue?

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39582684/qwebview-crash-when-loading-url)
I think QWebengine itself renders the html content without help of any other browser. But QWebview needs some other browser to render the html.

Comment: I think the answer on the link you provided sum it up... either switch to a new version or manually patch your copy of qt 5.3. I fail to see another alternative.